# Spring.NET with NHibernate and quartz transaction (global transaction manager)

Tags: spring, nhibernate, transactions, quartz-scheduler, spring.net

I want to use Global transaction manager at my service layer.

eg.

```
namespace AssemblyName.Core.Service.Implementation
{
    public class DemoService
    {

      public void demo() 
      {
           save(model); //This is nHibernate transaction
           SchedulerManager.GetInstance.save(id); //This is related to quartz.  
      }
    }       
}
```

What should I use?

If I used `TransactionScope()` then it is giving me error as NHibernateTransaction can't be committed.

I have used

```
<object id="transactionManager"
    type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate33">

    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>

</object>
```

in my sprin.config file.

Edited:
Then I have used two transaction manager in spring.config file:

```
<object id="transactionManager"type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager,Spring.DataNHibernate33">
        <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
        <property name="SessionFactory"ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
 </object>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
     <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
     </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<object id="serviceOperation" type="Spring.Aop.Support.SdkRegularExpressionMethodPointcut,Spring.Aop">
      <property name="pattern" value="AssemblyName.Core.Service.Implementation.*"/>
 </object>



<object id="transactionManagerGLobal" type="Spring.Data.Core.TxScopeTransactionManager, Spring.Data">
 </object>

<tx:advice id="txAdviceGlobal" transaction-manager="transactionManagerGLobal">
    <tx:attributes>
       <tx:method name="demo"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<object id="serviceOperationGlobal" type="Spring.Aop.Support.SdkRegularExpressionMethodPointcut, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="pattern" value="AssemblyName.Core.Service.Implementation.DemoService"/>
 </object>


<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperationGlobal" advice-ref="txAdviceGlobal"/>
</aop:config>
```

Then also getting Error as:
NHibernate Transaction is disconnected or not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my issue as following changes:

I have added tx annotation for NHibernate transaction :

```
<tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-type="true"/>
```

For Global Transaction I have changed my spring.config file as following and removed advisor 'serviceOperation' of NHibernate Transaction.:

```
<aop:config>
<aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperationGlobal" advice-ref="txAdviceGlobal"/>
```

Changes in my code:

```
namespace AssemblyName.Core.Service.Implementation
{          
      public class DemoService
      {
         [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Required)]
         public void demo()
         {
          save(model); //This is nHibernate transaction
          SchedulerManager.GetInstance.save(id); //This is related to quartz.
         }
       }       
}
```

Edited:
   By doing this Other problem introduced.
   It is running fine on many pc but in some pc it shows error : Connection was disconnected or not open, when I do operation related with demo().

I have configured all settings that need to run MS DTC.